# How is a client server model a distributed system?

Tags: client-server, distributed, middleware

I can not wrap my head around this one!
If I have a business which uses a web server to provide quotes and my employees can use this website to give quotes to customers, my business is a distributed system architecture because of the client server model? 
Where is the middleware here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**The clients are part of the distributed system.**

Example: a standard single-server website.

Since there's an asynchronous network between the clients (web browser) and the server (the internet), we could have network partitions. The clients need to send messages across this network since they need to fetch the website.